# Sonar - Failure because Class is not committed in svn?

Tags: maven, svn, sonarqube

I recently started using SonarQube on my Maven Java Project. The problem is that I modified a single line in a Class which causes Sonar failing to load the project into the database. Why does Sonar know that my project is checked into a SVN and why does `mvn sonar:sonar` fails with "can not blame XXX on line YYY" if a class is not committed into the SVN?

I am the only one working on this and I dont want to check in every single change or experimental code snipet. How can I turn this feature off?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCM integration (which detects that your projects uses SVN) allows SonarQube to track changes to source code, e.g to compute coverage on new code, new issues etc.

A standard analysis is supposed to be performed from commited code (e.g by a continuous integration server) to serve as a reference.

In your case, I would advise you to use the [incremental mode](http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube/): this will allow you to perform an analysis on your local code changes, which will not be persisted to the central server, but which will show you which issues your new code introduced/fixed (this is the analysis mode used by the IDE integration plugins).

Comment: Thank you! This will do it.